# I am checking if there are the same letters in two arrays, but can't seem to work when there are multiple same letters

Tags: arrays, input, dom-events, variable-assignment

So I've been given a task (check the Image) where I need to make a guessing game. It's specified to using an array for almost everything, so there is my problem. When I check for duplicates (same letters in the `guessedLetters` and `correctWord`), the code works until the second same letter occurs - which in this case is the E on the next-to-last index. Any clue how I can fix this, and even a solution to the worksheet?

```html
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>

    <style>
        .red {
            background-color: red;
        }

        .green {
            background-color: green;
        }

        p {
            width: 100px;
            height: 20px;
            background-color: black;
            color: white;
        }

        #msgOutput {
            background-color: wheat;
            color: black;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    
    <input type="text" id = "txtInp">
    <button>?</button>

    <p id = "msgOutput"></p>

    <p class="green"></p>
    <p class="green"></p>
    <p class="green"></p>
    <p class="green"></p>
    <p class="green"></p>

    <script>
        let correctWord = ["B", "E", "R", "G", "E", "N"];
        let input = document.querySelector("input");
        let guessBtn = document.querySelector("button");


        let guessedLetters = []
        let correctlyGuessedLetters = []

        const checkWord = () => {
            let guessedLetter = input.value.toUpperCase()
            guessedLetters.push(guessedLetter)
            

            for(let i = 0; i < guessedLetter.length; i++){
                for(let j = 0; j < correctWord.length; j++){
                    if(guessedLetter[i] == correctWord[j]){
                        console.log(`${guessedLetter[i]} og ${correctWord[j]} er like`)
                        correctlyGuessedLetters[correctWord.indexOf(guessedLetter[i])] = guessedLetter[i]
                    } else {
                        console.log(`${guessedLetter[i]} og ${correctWord[j]} er ikke like`)
                    }
                }
            }

            input.value = ""
            console.log(correctlyGuessedLetters)
        }


        guessBtn.addEventListener("click", checkWord)
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

[image: The task for the assignment]

I was expecting to get the `correctWord` in the `correctlyGuessedLetters` array, but it seems to not work for words with double letters?

Comment: `correctWord.indexOf(guessedLetter[i])` is always going to return the index of the FIRST match.  In this case, you don't need that at all.  You already know the index of the letter you're looking at -- it's in `j`.